# Troubleshooting UDP Code

Tags: c#, java, android, udp, wireshark

I'm working on a system to send data between peers on a network.  One app is written in Java for the Android.  The other app is written in C# on the PC.

I wrote code in Java on the Android to send UDP datagrams.  And I wrote C# code to both send and receive datagrams.  I tried to send messages from Android to PC.  I could see the message in WireShark but not in my program.  So, I put my program on a second PC.  I succeeded in sending a message from my PC to the second one.  But when I tried to send a message from seond PC back to mine it failed.  I could see it in WireShark on my PC but not my application.  Im at a loss for what to try next.  Do you have any suggestions?  Why would the UDP packet be visible in WireShark but not my application?

```
Here is my code.

//C# code on PC
//Sender
sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, rotocolType.Udp);
send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(strIPAddress);
sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, intPort);
sending_socket.EnableBroadcast = true;
byte[] bytMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMessage);
sending_socket.SendTo(bytMessage, sending_end_point);



//Listener
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
byte[] bytReceiveDataByteArray;
try
{
   listener.EnableBroadcast = true;

   while (isRunning)
   {
      //listen for data from sender
      bytReceiveDataByteArray = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
      //Fire an event to send the data to the hosting code
      if (DataReceived != null)
      {
         DataReceivedEventArgs e = new DataReceivedEventArgs(bytReceiveDataByteArray);
         DataReceived(this, e);
      }
   }
}


//Java code on Android
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress serverIP = InetAddress.getByName(strIpAddress);
byte[] outData = (strMsg).getBytes();
DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(outData,outData.length, serverIP,50005);
socket.send(out);
socket.close();
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why would you use UDP? UDP doesn't do packets error control. You have to make sure by yourself that your packets are ordered, not deleted or duplicated. Do you have more than 2 peers? I recommand you to use TCP if it doesn't have any impacts on your application performance.

Comment: Im afraid it would.  This is for a Wii-type video game.  The game runs on the PC and the Android is used for the controller.  The PC will send images to the Android.  And the Android will send accelerometer info back to the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correct when your program runs on a specific PC (lets call it "Windows1") it never receives the UDP packets. It will not receive them from Java Android or from C# code running on a different PC ( lets call it "Windows2").

However when you run your program on "Windows2" it DOES receive messages from "Windows1".  Sounds like you have the firewall enabled on "Windows1" and do not have an exception for UDP port 50005.   On "Windows2" your firewall is turned off or has the exception for 50005 and this is why it receives messages from "Windows1".

Note that since UDP is not connection oriented, firewall errors will not cause the usual connection timed out error.  The messages are just dropped and you never get an error.

Comment: Thanks!  That gives me something to check.  I do have a question though.  If the firewall is stopping it, how can WireShark see it?

Comment: I added a rule to my firewall for that UDP port. now i can send messages back and forth between Windows1 and Windows2.  That part is fully functional.  But, i still cant get packets from Android.  I even tried turning the firewall completely off and they still wont come through.  I know the packet is coming across because i can see it on Windows1 with WireShark.  But, for some reason, my C# application still cant see it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay.  Now i have the Android code working to.  my issue was with the fact that i had forgotten that my original code had the port number hard coded.  you even mentioned the port number twice in your response and i still didnt think about it.